# Android Change selector's color in runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to change the selector's gradient colors on runtime. How do i program it??

The following is a selector's XML.

```
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffff0000"
                android:endColor="#ffff00ff"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#ffff0d00"
                android:startColor="#ffff00d0"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this bit of code

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_selector_file);
yourview.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: i want to change color dynamic without changing the shape. Also, i do not want to define many XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

Use GradientDrawable. e.g. `new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { 0xffff0000, 0xffff00ff});`